# Html format to send for ajax request not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to get the html format before sending it to the ajax request.But there happens an error like this : `Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < - parsererror - [object Object]`

I just want to make a select options by the values from an array.Here is the code :

```
$args = array(
    'type'        => 'ad_listing',
        'child_of'    => $parent_cat,
        'orderby'     => 'name',
        'order'       => 'ASC',
        // 'hide_empty'  => 1,
        // 'hierarchical'=> 1,
        'exclude'     => '',
        'include'     => '',
        'number'      => '',
        'taxonomy'    => 'ad_cat',
        'pad_counts'  => false 
);

$results = get_categories( $args );

$result = '<select>';
foreach ($results as $key => $value) {

    $result .= '<option>' . $value . '</option>';

}
return $result .= '</select>';

// return the result to the ajax post
die( json_encode( array( 'success' => true, 'html' => $result ) ) );
```

Here `$result` would be the html format i want to send..Here the error comes : `Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < - parsererror - [object Object]`

But if i use the code in this way i get the array object:

```
    $args = array(
    'type'        => 'ad_listing',
        'child_of'    => $parent_cat,
        'orderby'     => 'name',
        'order'       => 'ASC',
        // 'hide_empty'  => 1,
        // 'hierarchical'=> 1,
        'exclude'     => '',
        'include'     => '',
        'number'      => '',
        'taxonomy'    => 'ad_cat',
        'pad_counts'  => false 
);

$result = get_categories( $args );


// return the result to the ajax post
die( json_encode( array( 'success' => true, 'html' => $result ) ) );
```

I am sure that i am doing something wrong :(

Comment: What's `var_dump($results)` say?

Comment: How can i get that? I need to send result to ajax request

Comment: If you send the result to an ajax request go right into the ajax request in client side code, put console.log(result) and check the output in your console.

Comment: Yes i get this : `object{sucess: true, html:object}`

Answer (score 0):

As I assume this is a WordPress question get_categories returns an array of objects (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories).

Do the following:

```
foreach($results as $cat) {
$result .= '<option>'.$cat->name.'</option>';
}
```

... or whatever you need according to the WordPress Codex documentation.

Comment: It returns categories not found

Comment: Check your $args. If no categories are found there is most probably something wrong with your arguments or there are just no categories which match your specified arguments?

Comment: But when i get the result in `console` then i get the Categories in `object`

Comment: $results should definitly be an array of objects. Each of these objects in $results should have keys and values?

Comment: You can get the console results from here after selecting a category : http://www.sayulitalife.com/exchange/create-listing/